# loading in android with webview and refresh button

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView in my app, but when there is no internet connection it will show the normal webpage from google that says, "no internet connection." I want would rather it show two things:

1) If there is no internet connection I want there to say "No internet connection" and have a refresh button.

2) When the app starts, or when it tries to connect, it will show a progress bar/loading screen.

Here is some WebView script:

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewF);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String url = "http://m.facebook.com/";
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl(url);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());





public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{


    @Override

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
         if (errorCode == ERROR_CONNECT)
         {
              What should i write here ??!!!

         }
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `WebView` class (create a class and extends it) and implement [`onReceivedError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Report an error to the host application. These errors are
>   unrecoverable (i.e. the main resource is unavailable). The errorCode
>   parameter corresponds to one of the ERROR_* constants.
>
> Parameters 
>   **view**  The WebView that is initiating the callback.
>
> **errorCode** The error code corresponding to an ERROR_* value.
>
> **description**   A String describing the error. failingUrl   The url that
>   failed to load.

There are the errors which you can handle:

```
int ERROR_AUTHENTICATION    User authentication failed on server
int ERROR_BAD_URL   Malformed URL
int ERROR_CONNECT   Failed to connect to the server
int ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE  Failed to perform SSL handshake
int ERROR_FILE  Generic file error
int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    File not found
int ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP   Server or proxy hostname lookup failed
int ERROR_IO    Failed to read or write to the server
int ERROR_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION  User authentication failed on proxy
int ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP Too many redirects
int ERROR_TIMEOUT   Connection timed out
int ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS Too many requests during this load
int ERROR_UNKNOWN   Generic error
int ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_AUTH_SCHEME   Unsupported authentication scheme (not basic or digest)
int ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME    Unsupported URI scheme
```

For your #2 thing, use `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished`.

Comment: haa . i don't understand the first part where i will add to the webview code wish when no connection it will tell the user no internet connection try again

Comment: It should be ERROR_CONNECT which is called when fails to connect.

Comment: ok but sorry i mean where should i write it in the code and how . i mean coding way . see my code and tell me how to edit it

Comment: As i said, you should create another class which extends WebView and override the method.

Comment: 1. Right now you should start use myWebClient as View and not default WebView. 2. What int ERROR_CONNECT; means? You should do something if (errorCode == WHAT_ERROR_YOU_WANT_HANDLE) { /* handle it */ }

Comment: ohh ok i got it . so it will apply to all the webView as long it use the webClient

ok i edit my Question again see it please .. u really helping me

Comment: "What should i write here ??!!!" => WHat you want to do when this error happens? It's what you should write (with return; so you avoid to call default method)

Comment: yeah i understand but i don't know how to write it . i want if no internet connection it will show a message said "sorry there is no internet connection Please reopen the app when u have it " then it will close the app

Comment: Then do: Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); finish();